# Know if an array contains a type of element

Tags: arrays, swift, nodes, contains, skspritenode

I'm working with Swift 3 and Xcode.

I have a class :

```
class H: SKSpriteNode {...}
```

And an array :

```
var array = [H]()
```

I want to check with the `nodes(at:)` function if at given point, there is an element of type H. I tried :

```
if nodes(at: myPoint).contains(H)
```

But it doesn't work, and I understand that. Is there any way to be able to know if the arrays the `nodes(at)` function returns contains an element from the class H ?

And an other question, how can I check in all the nodes returned by the function, if the array contains a node with a specific name ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to use `.filter({ $0 is H }).count > 0` or `.contains(where: { $0 is H })`

Comment: It's working, thanks. And .filter({$0.name is "something"}).count > 0 would work too ?

Comment: Better: `.contains { $0 is H }`

Comment: Do you have any tutorial explaining this whole $0 thing ? I've never seen this notation before. And  according to Swift, the right syntax is : .contains(where: {$0 is H})

Comment: sure. here you go [link](https://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/)

Comment: @Drakalex .filter({$0.name is "something"}).count > 0 wouldn't work, cause "is" in comparing classes, not values. You should use .filter({$0.name == "something"}).count > 0 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Update as of Swift 4.2

```
//Where
class H: UIViewController { }
var myArray: [UIViewController] = [ unknownViewController, anotherUnknown )]
//Then
let doesContainH = myArray.contains(where: { $0 is H })
```

As Martin R points out, we can now use `.contains(where: { $0 is Type } )`